# Opening file present in another folder which has same relative path as current opened file in vim using vertical diffsplit?

Tags: vim, cd, vimdiff

Say I have following 2 similar files in 2 different workspace on same linux machine.

```
/user1/ws1/ip/src/ip_main.c 
/user1/ws2/ip/src/ip_main.c
```

Now I did,

```
cd user1/ws1/ 
vim ip/src/ip_main.c
```

then I press `ESC` then executed

```
:cd ../ws2
```

which shows my pwd as "`user1/ws2`" 
Now I want to open `ip/src/ip_main.c` in pwd i.e "`user1/ws2`" 
using `ESC`

```
:vertical diffsplit "some logic to get to ws2/ip/src/ip_main.c"
```

**note** after `:cd ../ws2`

`:pwd` command show `"user1/ws2"` but `:echo $PWD` command still show `"user1/ws1"`

How can i do it,Can anyone help ?

Comment: your first `cd user1` would be `cd user1/ws1` right? otherwise later `:cd ../ws2` won't work.

Comment: @Kent Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Diffing both files is easily done via *shell globbing*, e.g. in Bash:

```
$ vimdiff -O /user1/ws{1,2}/ip/src/ip_main.c
```

Withing Vim, you have to use *relative paths* (i.e. prepend `../..`, then go down into the other hierarchy). `<C-R>%` on the command-line (cp. `:help c_CTRL-R`) inserts the current path; this may avoid retyping much of the similar path, especially when used with the *command-line window* (`:help c_CTRL-F`).

With my [EditSimilar plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2544), you can use this:

```
:DiffSplitSubstitute 1=2
```